# Create virtual env on machine without internet connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I'm trying to use pipenv on a machine that has limited internet connection. When I run pipenv install, it creates the pipfile. But when it tries to create the virtualenv it just stops and is just thinking. Is it possible to create an virtualenv without it trying to connect to the internet?

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\habr08\Utveckling\Python\Projects\Tensorflow\Pipfile
Using c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe (3.7.2) to create 
virtualenv…
[=   ] Creating virtual environment...
```

In the end I get this error message

```
FAIL
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File 
"C:\\Users\\habr08\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site- 
packages\\pipenv\\vendor\\vistir\\contextmanagers.py", line 150, in 
spinner\n    yield _spinner\n', '  File 
"C:\\Users\\habr08\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site- 
packages\\pipenv\\vendor\\vistir\\misc.py", line 314, in run\n    
write_to_stdout=True\n', '  File 
"C:\\Users\\habr08\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site- 
packages\\pipenv\\vendor\\vistir\\misc.py", line 236, in 
_create_subprocess\n    c.out, c.err = c.communicate()\n', '  File 
"c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 939, in 
communicate\n    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, 
timeout)\n', '  File "c:\\program files (x86)\\python37- 
32\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 1267, in _communicate\n    
self.stdout_thread.join(self._remaining_time(endtime))\n', '  File 
"c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\lib\\threading.py", line 1032, in 
join\n    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()\n', '  File "c:\\program files 
(x86)\\python37-32\\lib\\threading.py", line 1048, in 
_wait_for_tstate_lock\n    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):\n', '  File 
"C:\\Users\\habr08\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site- 
packages\\pipenv\\vendor\\yaspin\\signal_handlers.py", line 23, in 
default_handler\n    sys.exit(0)\n', 'SystemExit: 0\n']
c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py:858: ResourceWarning: 
subprocess 4504 is still running
ResourceWarning, source=self)
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: @khelwood Hope thats better.

Comment: Yes, much better.